# Prevent closing the dialog on disabled action button click

Tags: angular, typescript, mat-dialog

I want to prevent closing the dialog when a user clicks on the action button which is disabled.

```
    <mat-dialog-actions>
    <lib-button mat-dialog-close>{{ cancel }}</lib-button>
    <lib-button [disabled]="isFormInvalid" [mat-dialog-close]="data.form">{{
      confirm }}</lib-button>
  </mat-dialog-actions>
```

library:

```
    <button
  mat-button
  [type]="type"
  [ngClass]="matType"
  [color]="backgroundColor"
  [fxFlex]="setFxFlex ? 'auto' : 'initial'"
  [disabled]="disabled"
  (click)="onClick.emit($event)"
  [style.height]="size"
  [style.width]="size"
>
  <lib-icon *ngIf="materialIcon">
    {{ materialIcon }}
  </lib-icon>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</button>
```

This is the code and I expected it to work, but it doesn't. Though the button is shown as disabled but it still closes the dialog when a user clicks on it.

Any lead is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Based on the code we are seeing it should work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kezpqy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdialog-overview-example.html Please provide a [mcve] that shows your issue.

Comment: @AT82 don't know how to reproduce it, since the entire code is complex but I have edited the question with more details. The button used inside the action items is from library, don't know if this has anything to do with it. Though when opened inside the library, it doesn't emit any event when disabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
<... [mat-dialog-close]="{action:'delete', data: data.id}">

<... [mat-dialog-close]="{action:'close'}">

<... [mat-dialog-close]="{action:'save', data: data.form}">
```

You can send your action to the method and in `switch` case you can perform operation.